# How do you say "Toilet Seat"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen this question asked on other sites and believe it or not, we discussed it at NASK (2016) in the advanced class. There was some disagreement on whether *seĝo* means the whole throne or whether it can refer to just the seat (the movable ring that you sit on.)

Where there was agreement, though, was that *neceseja seĝo* clearly and unambiguously refers to the whole appliance, not just the seat. Myself, I learned *truseĝo* for the seat. Others suggested *sidilo* - which I always understood as an expression meaning "back side."

Is there any consensus on this question?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about consensus, but *sidilo* is something to sit on (a chair, usually) and it is quite logical to say it is the surface you sit on in a *necesejo*. It is part of the *neceseja seĝo*. Other parts of the throne are the *pelvo* (bowl) under the *sidilo*, the *klapo* (lid) of the *sidilo* and the (perhaps hidden) *akvujo*.

I looked in the *Bildvoraro de Esperanto* and it uses these words. I might say also *kovrilo* instead of *klapo* but *kovrilo* could also be understood as something extra on the seat or on the lid. The *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro* says *fekseĝo* for *neceseja seĝo* or *necesseĝo*- *Fekseĝo* is easy to understand but I don't like the word very much.

If *sidilo* seems ambiguous you could perhaps say *sidsurfaco* or *sidplato*.